# How to get html elements from a string?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dom

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC 4 site and there is a function where I parse emails via Pop3 protocol. So after I fetch an email, I have the html coded email in a string. I want to use the html DOM elements like classes and id-s, to get data from the email. It would be simple if I can use jQuery, but I do not find any way to use it. Is there any solution to use something like jQuery from an MVC Controller to select the proper data?

Comment: Try the Html Agility Pack. You can get it through Nuget.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`HTML Agility Pack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) library to parse and manipulate HTML from .NET code. Check [`this post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack) out for getting started.